# In Haskell, when do we use in with let?

Tags: haskell, scope, whitespace, where-clause, let

In the following code, the last phrase I can put an `in` in front. Will it change anything?

Another question: If I decide to put `in` in front of the last phrase, do I need to indent it?

I tried without indenting and hugs complains

> Last generator in do {...} must be an expression

```
import Data.Char
groupsOf _ [] = []
groupsOf n xs = 
    take n xs : groupsOf n ( tail xs )

problem_8 x = maximum . map product . groupsOf 5 $ x
main = do t <- readFile "p8.log" 
          let digits = map digitToInt $concat $ lines t
          print $ problem_8 digits
```

---

#### Edit

Ok, so people don't seem to understand what I'm saying. Let me rephrase:
are the following two the same, given the context above?

1.

```
let digits = map digitToInt $concat $ lines t
print $ problem_8 digits
```

2.

```
let digits = map digitToInt $concat $ lines t
in print $ problem_8 digits
```

Another question concerning the scope of bindings declared in `let`: I read [here](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html) that:

> `where` Clauses.

Sometimes it is convenient to scope bindings over several guarded equations, which requires a where clause:

```
f x y  |  y>z           =  ...
       |  y==z          =  ...
       |  y<z           =  ...
     where z = x*x
```

Note that this cannot be done with a let expression, which only scopes over the expression **which it encloses**.

My question: so, the variable digits shouldn't be visible to the last print phrase. Do I miss something here?

Comment: Do you know what `do` notation really means or is it a black box to you? Knowing its guts, everything you mention seems perfectly intuitive to me. Of course, intuition will only get one so far without understanding of the prequisites...

Comment: OK Now i get the indentation part. Basically if i don't indent, "do" will consider it as an independent task, same level as let. Another question: do i have to use let to declare variables ?

Comment: @osager: Haskell doesn't really have "variables". You can bind "values" to a given name. If you really want to have a cell in memory that you can modify with different values during the execution of your program, you'll need to use an `IORef` or similar. But newbies are generally encouraged to learn about the functional way of doing things, which vigorously avoids modifying the value of a reference.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I also come to realize(to my big surprise) that haskell doesn't really use the notion of variable !  But still, i find the syntax of Haskell more difficult to grasp than the mindset of functional programming !

Answer (score 158, accepted):

**Short answer**: Use `let` without `in` in the body of a do-block, and in the part after the `|` in a list comprehension. Anywhere else, use `let ... in ...`.

---

The keyword `let` is used in three ways in Haskell.

1. The first form is a *let-expression*.

   ```
   let variable = expression in expression
   ```

   This can be used wherever an expression is allowed, e.g.

   ```
   > (let x = 2 in x*2) + 3
   7
   ```
2. The second is a *let-statement*. This form is only used inside of do-notation, and does not use `in`.

   ```
   do statements
      let variable = expression
      statements
   ```
3. The third is similar to number 2 and is used inside of list comprehensions. Again, no `in`.

   ```
   > [(x, y) | x <- [1..3], let y = 2*x]
   [(1,2),(2,4),(3,6)]
   ```

   This form binds a variable which is in scope in subsequent generators and in the expression before the `|`.

---

The reason for your confusion here is that expressions (of the correct type) can be used as statements within a do-block, and `let .. in ..` is just an expression.

Because of the indentation rules of haskell, a line indented further than the previous one means it's a continuation of the previous line, so this

```
do let x = 42 in
     foo
```

gets parsed as

```
do (let x = 42 in foo)
```

Without indentation, you get a parse error:

```
do (let x = 42 in)
   foo
```

In conclusion, never use `in` in a list comprehension or a do-block. It is unneccesary and confusing, as those constructs already have their own form of `let`.

Comment: Is there any difference between forms 2 and 3 at all? I though they were actually the same, after expanding `[RET | SRC1, SRC2, ...]` to `do SRC1 ⏎ SRC2 ⏎ ... ⏎ return RET`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: They used to be in an older version of Haskell. Then list comprehensions were limited to lists only, while do-notation worked for any monad. However, GHC 7.2.1 brings this feature back again `MonadComprehensions` extension.

Comment: Very minor: the LHS in a let-binding is a pattern match, not just a variable binding.

Comment: This answer just needs a small comment about GHCi kinda being in a perpetual do block now.

Comment: I realised that you cannot write something like `let x = x + 1`. I assumed it was like variable assignment like `let x = 1 ; let x = x +1` would increment x to 2. But since let is recursive, x just becomes an infinite expression. You cannot reassign variables unless you do something like `x <- return (x + 1)`. Is there a way to make let non-recursive?

Comment: The do-block is a syntactic sugar for `>>= \x` or `>>`, if I desugar it, how would I translate the second way of writing a let?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai no (as you have probably already discovered by now). in Haskell `let` bindings are always recursive.

Comment: @ptkato `do { x <- xs ; let {a = b} ; c <- cs ; foo x a c }` is `do { x <- xs ; let {a = b} in do { c <- cs ; foo x a c } }` is `xs >>= (\ x -> let {a = b} in cs >>= (\ c -> foo x a c ))`. with the explicit `{ ; }` separators there's no whitespace fragility.

Answer (score 26):

First off, why hugs? The [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) is generally the recommended way to go for newbies, which comes with GHC.

Now then, on to the `let`keyword. The simplest form of this keyword is meant to *always* be used with `in`.

```
let {assignments} in {expression}
```

For example,

```
let two = 2; three = 3 in two * three
```

**The `{assignments}` are *only* in scope in the corresponding `{expression}`.** Regular layout rules apply, meaning that `in` must be indented at least as much as the `let` that it corresponds to, and any sub-expressions pertaining to the `let` expression must likewise be indented at least as much. This isn't actually 100% true, but is a good rule of thumb; Haskell layout rules are something you will just get used to over time as you read and write Haskell code. Just keep in mind that the amount of indentation is the main way to indicate which code pertains to what expression.

Haskell provides two convenience cases where you *don't* have to write `in`: do notation and list comprehensions (actually, monad comprehensions). The scope of the assignments for these convenience cases is predefined.

```
do foo
   let {assignments}
   bar
   baz
```

For `do` notation, the `{assignments}` are in scope for any statements that follow, in this case, `bar` and `baz`, but not `foo`. It is as if we had written

```
do foo
   let {assignments}
   in do bar
         baz
```

List comprehensions (or really, any monad comprehension) desugar into do notation, so they provide a similar facility.

```
[ baz | foo, let {assignments}, bar ]
```

The `{assignments}` are in scope for the expressions `bar` and `baz`, but not for `foo`.

---

`where` is somewhat different. If I'm not mistaken, the scope of `where` lines up with a particular function definition. So

```
someFunc x y | guard1 = blah1
             | guard2 = blah2
  where {assignments}
```

the `{assignments}` in this `where` clause have access to `x` and `y`. `guard1`, `guard2`, `blah1`, and `blah2` *all* have access to the `{assignments}` of this `where` clause. As is mentioned in the tutorial you linked, this can be helpful if multiple guards reuse the same expressions.

Comment: Also i chose Hugs because it offers a little bit more features than winghci such as code browsing. I DO wonder if these two are compatible or not, especially for third party libraries. The other day i've installed a library and winghci found it but not Hugs.

Comment: Thanks. This was also the only place I found the semi-colon, e.g. `let a = 1; b = 2 in ...`

Answer (score 8):

In `do` notation, you can indeed use `let` with and without `in`. For it to be equivalent (in your case, I'll later show an example where you need to add a second `do` and thus more indentation), you need to indent it as you discovered (if you're using layout - if you use explicit braces and semicolons, they're exactly equivalent).

To understand *why* it's equivalent, you have to actually grok monads (at least to some degree) and look at the desugaring rules for `do` notation. In particular, code like this:

```
do let x = ...
   stmts -- the rest of the do block
```

is translated to `let x = ... in do { stmts }`. In your case, `stmts = print (problem_8 digits)`. Evaluating the whole desugared `let` binding results in an IO action (from `print $ ...`). And here, you need understanding of monads to intuitively agree that there's no difference between `do` notations and "regular" language elements describing a computation resulting in monadic values.

As for both why are possible: Well, `let ... in ...` has a broad range of applications (most of which have nothing to do with monads in particular), and a long history to boot. `let` without `in` for `do` notation, on the other hand, seems to be nothing but a small piece of syntactic sugar. The advantage is obvious: You can bind the results of pure (as in, not monadic) computations to a name without resorting to a pointless `val <- return $ ...` and without splitting up the `do` block in two:

```
do stuff
   let val = ...
    in do more
          stuff $ using val
```

The reason you don't need an extra `do` block for what follows the `let` is that you only got a single line. Remember, `do e` is `e`.

Regarding your edit: `digit` being visible in the next line is the whole point. And there's no exception for it or anything. `do` notation becomes one single expression, and `let` works just fine in a single expression. `where` is only needed for things which aren't expressions.

For the sake of demonstration, I'll show the desugared version of your `do` block. If you aren't too familiar with monads yet (something you should change soon IMHO), ignore the `>>=` operator and focus on the `let`. Also note that indentation doesn't matter any more.

```
main = readFile "p8.log" >>= (\t ->
  let digits = map digitToInt $ concat $ lines t
  in print (problem_8 digits))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'd probably hang myself before i can even reach the monad chapter.

Comment: @osager Bind and return are the 2 functions that make monads useful, but when it comes to building an understanding of what monads actually are it's better to think of them in terms of fmap and join.

Comment: @McBearHolden the diagram in my user picture helped me a lot. there's also links in my profile. monad is just a type `M` with a special kind of generalized application / composition, `(a -> M b) -> (b -> M c) -> (a -> M c)` (which fulfills some "obvious" laws, like associativity and existence of identity `a -> M a` w.r.t. the composition), like the regular application composition is `(a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)` (where `(.)` is associative and `id :: a -> a` exists for any `a`). there's also the [tag:do-notation] SO tag and its [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/do-notation/info).

Answer (score 1):

Some beginner notes about "are following two the same".

For example, `add1` is a function, that add 1 to number:

```
add1 :: Int -> Int
add1 x =
    let inc = 1
    in x + inc
```

So, it's like `add1 x = x + inc` with substitution inc by 1 from `let` keyword.

When you try to suppress `in` keyword

```
add1 :: Int -> Int
add1 x =
    let inc = 1
    x + inc
```

you've got parse error.

From [documentation](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords#let):

```
Within do-blocks or list comprehensions 
let { d1 ; ... ; dn } 
without `in` serves to introduce local bindings.
```

Btw, there are [nice explanation](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where) with many examples about what `where` and `in` keyword actually do.