# GHCi "let" -- what does it do?

Tags: haskell, ghci, let

I'd appreciate if someone could point to docs on what "let" does in GHCi, or failing that, explain it convincingly.

So far as I can tell, "let" (without "in") is not part of the Haskell language per se, and on the other hand, it doesn't appear to be a GHCi command either, as it's not prefixed by colon.

Comment: Short answer: `let` (without `in`) *is* part of the Haskell language, when inside a `do` block (and writing in GHCi resembles writing in the `IO` monad).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

While programming in GHCi, you're like programming in the IO monad with `do` syntax, so for example you can directly execute an `IO` action, or use monadic bind syntax like `r <- someIOFun`.

`let` is also a part of `do` so you can also use this. I think it's being desugared into `let .. in <rest of the computation>`, so for example when you do this:

```
ghci> let a = 1
ghci> someFun
ghci> someFun2
```

It's like:

```
let a = 1 in
do someFun
   someFun2
```

Comment: Its not just `IO ()` but any `IO` action of type `IO a`.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, and relates GHCi let to Haskell let... in do.

Comment: `let` without `in` is allowed within a do-block and is not equivalent to the example you give (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274650/in-haskell-when-do-we-use-in-with-let)

Comment: That desugared word threw me for a bit.  Thought it was des-u-gared.  Had no idea what it meant.

Answer (score 12):

Here's the relevant part of the [documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html).

GHCI statements are executed as IO computation. So `let` is same as what you have inside an `IO` monad where you bind non-IO expression using `let`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the docs, I hadn't found that. As a side comment, that doc is rather disappointing, since its explanation of let is sort of premised on understanding monads. New users encounter let almost immediately as it's frequently presented in tutorials on beginning Haskell concepts, yet it doesn't work if copied to a haskell source file, and explanations assuming understanding of monads are not too useful. Nonetheless, with the collection of answers here I at least see how these features fit together.

Comment: @gwideman Yeah, I understand that. You can not directly copy what you write as ghci statements in a hs file and expect them to work. Well you can ofcourse do `main = do <your ghci statements>`. It might not work always as expected as ghci prints the output of a statement by using its `Show` instance.

Answer (score 9):

For more down-to-the-code details, this comment in [TcRnDriver.lhs](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/typecheck/TcRnDriver.lhs#L1298) might be enlighting:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Typechecking Stmts in GHCi

Here is the grand plan, implemented in tcUserStmt

        What you type The IO [HValue] that hscStmt returns
        ------------- ------------------------------------
        let pat = expr ==> let pat = expr in return [coerce HVal x, coerce HVal y, ...]
                                        bindings: [x,y,...]

        pat <- expr ==> expr >>= \ pat -> return [coerce HVal x, coerce HVal y, ...]
                                        bindings: [x,y,...]

        expr (of IO type) ==> expr >>= \ it -> return [coerce HVal it]
          [NB: result not printed] bindings: [it]

        expr (of non-IO type, ==> let it = expr in print it >> return [coerce HVal it]
          result showable) bindings: [it]

        expr (of non-IO type,
          result not showable) ==> error
```

So a command at the GHCi prompt can have up to three effects: Some code is evaluated, some things are printed, and some variable names are bound. Your case (the first one in the comment) binds variables, but does not print.

The syntax does resemble the do-notation, so @sinan’s answer is somewhat right, but it is not really what is happening under the hood – otherwise, for example, nothing would ever be printed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't understand all of that at this stage, but it is very useful to see the degree to which one should not learn from GHCi :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

GHCI commands are executed in the IO monad and uses do syntax, so the desugaring rules apply. From [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html#monads.do)

```
doNotation4 =
    do let val1 = expr1
           val2 = expr2
           {- ... etc. -}
           valN = exprN
       act1
       act2
       {- ... etc. -}
       actN
```

translates to:

```
translated4 =
    let val1 = expr1
        val2 = expr2
        {- ... etc. -}
        valN = exprN
    in do act1
          act2
          {- ... etc. -}
          actN
```

Comment: OK, this makes a lot of sense.