# Haskell, a simple pattern matching gets error

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

```
let countList (x:xs) = 1+countList xs
let countList [] = 0
countList [1,2,3]
*** Exception: <interactive>:35:5-20: Non-exhaustive patterns in function countList
```

I think that's too simple to get an error, but an error is still there
I'm shocked

Comment: You're shocked ? Oops.

Comment: it's correct when i use case-of to match them

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using multiple `let` statements means you're really defining *two* functions, with the second definition shadowing the first one. Thus, `countList [1, 2, 3]` throws an exception because the definition that's in scope is only defined for `[]`.

You need to define both equations at the same time with a single `let`. You can either type them on one line, separating the cases with a semicolon

```
> let countList (x:xs) = 1 + countList xs; countList [] = 0
```

or use GHCi's multiline syntax `:{ ... :}`, making sure to align the second `countList` with the first one.

```
> :{
| let countList (x:xs) = 1 + countList xs
|     countList [] = 0
| :}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're working in GHCi. The problem with your code is that you're not defining two cases of a pattern match on a single function, but that you're just redefining the function itself. Thus you get the `let countList (x:xs) = 1+countList xs` part replaced by `let countList [] = 0`, which is in fact a non-exhaustive pattern-match.

Answer (score 0):

You're redefining `countList` function instead of extending the existing definition with more pattern guards. I'm not sure if there is a way to do what you want to do, in GHCi(other than using `case ... of ...` expressions).

See also this: [GHCi "let" -- what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052093/ghci-let-what-does-it-do/14052220#14052220)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use let? 
If not, this is simplest.

```
countList [] = 0
countList (x:xs) = 1 + countList xs
```

The condition for 0 should be before the generic condition.