# Calling Haskell script on mac?

Tags: haskell, directory, ghci

I've installed [the Haskell platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/) on my mac (OSX lion), and `ghci` is running great.

Now I've created a haskell-file, stored on my "desk." How can I call it from this directory?

**Example:**

```
Prelude> :load datei.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( datei.hs, interpreted )

datei.hs:1:7: parse error on input `\'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

**`datei.hs:`**

```
let fac n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * fac (n-1)
```

Why do I get this?

Comment: there is no ` \ ` in what you linked.  There must be more input.  And haskell isn't an ML you don't need to let to declare functions.  Just `fac 0 = if n == 0 then 1 else n * fac (n-1)` will work.  But most people would write it like this `fac n = product [1..n]` or `fac 0 = 1` `fac n = n * fac (n-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [OSX terminal](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line) to reach your desktop and invoke *yourfile.hs* using ghci:

```
cd ~/Desktop
ghci yourfile.hs
```

**edit:**

As stated in the comments, the error message you're seeing above is warning you that the character `\` exists at an unexpected location in the source code.

Since that character does not exist in the line of code you posted, there must be more to *datei.hs*. We need to see the rest of your source code before we can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you saved your program with TextEdit, it's very possible that you're seeing a '\' character because you're saving it as an RTF file (TextEdit's default). Hit Ctrl-shift-t to convert it into a plain text file.

Answer (score 0):

If your already in ghci you can use ':cd /path/to/file' as well.

Here is a good thread discussing [let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052093/ghci-let-what-does-it-do).