# Haskell parse error with ghci with 'let'

Tags: parsing, haskell, jupyter, ghci, let

I've been sitting around here for quite some time now and my problem just won't solve by googling, try and error. I've got the following code snippet:

```
data Prozess = Prozess { pid :: Int, arrival :: Int, computing :: Int } deriving (Show)

let idle = Prozess{pid=1, arrival=5, computing=10}
```

So I tried to compile it with ghci, but it's keep giving me a "parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)" at the "let idle ..."-line. Weird thing is, I tried compiling this using our Jupyter-Server  and that seems to work nicely. Also, if I compile it without the "let"-line and input the -exact- same line afterwards via Terminal in *Main>, it's working fine too.

So what's wrong with ghci? Think I'm losing my mind over this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GHCi "let" -- what does it do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052093/ghci-let-what-does-it-do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `let` isn't in any function is it?

If you're just defining a global "constant", you just go:

```
idle :: Prozess
idle = Prozess{pid=1, arrival=5, computing=10}
```

Also, note that you don't need the record notation. You can swap that for:

`idle  = Prozess 1 5 10`

Comment: Heaven just opened it's doors for me. God bless you and your family. And stuff. ;-)