# Still confused by 'let' in GHCi

Tags: haskell

I have read the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052093/ghci-let-what-does-it-do), but I am still confused. In both GHCi (version 8.2.1) and WinGHCi (version 1.0.6), running in Windows 10, I appear to be able to bind a value to an expression, when typing at the prompt, both with and without using let (see below). And similarly I appear to be able to define identically performing functions by both *let f x = x*x* and *f x = x*x*

```
Prelude> x = 3
Prelude> let y = 3
Prelude> x
3
Prelude> y
3
Prelude> x == y
True
Prelude>
```

So when is the let actually *necessary* in GHCi?

In case it is relevant, the language flags set for GHCi (which I presume are default values as I haven't messed whth them) are

```
base language is: Haskell2010
with the following modifiers:
  -XNoDatatypeContexts
  -XExtendedDefaultRules
  -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
  -XNondecreasingIndentation
```

Comment: I think you didn’t used to be able to do that, but if you can now that’s nice. Maybe it’s only there for backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 5):

In answer to my own question. I have just read the footnote

> This has changed as of the release of GHC 8.0.1; using let in declarations in GHCi
>   is no longer necessary. As we assume most readers of this edition will be using an
>   earlier version of GHC, we have kept the let notation throughout the book, and this
>   shouldn’t cause any errors or breakage.

in *Haskell Programming From First Principles*, which confirms that **let** is no longer necessary.