# Using `let ... in` with Function

Tags: haskell

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#command-line-arguments) presents the `shortLines` function:

```
shortLinesOnly :: String -> String  
shortLinesOnly input =   
    let allLines = lines input  
        shortLines = filter (\line -> length line < 10) allLines  
        result = unlines shortLines  
    in  result
```

From this helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8274846/409976), it seems clear to me that the following `let ... in` is correct:

```
> (let x = 2 in x*2) + 3
7
```

But, in the above `shortLinesOnly` example, why is the `let`'s `in` placed at `in result`?

Comment: Where else might it be placed?

Comment: @KevinMeredith This is a multi-line `let-in` statement.  The `let-in` syntax lets you define one or more intermediate values that can be used in the expression following the `in`.  This is like with `where` statements in which you can define as many local expressions as you want.  There are some subtleties between let-in and where, namely that `let ... in ...` can be used in sub-expressions.  You couldn't write the above as `(x * 2 where x = 2) + 3`, Haskell doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 4):

`let ... in ...` allows *multiple* declarations to come between the `let` and the `in`, and then a single expression after the `in` which is the final value of the entire `let ... in ...` expression. All the declarations are in scope for the expression (and for the body of each of the declarations).

So both the examples you give are valid - the simple one is just making a single declaration (`x = 2`) whereas the more complicated one is defining three things (`allLines = ...`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

When you see `let A in B` you can think of `B` as the value of the statement. In an imperative language, you might write it as `A; return B`.

We could also have written the code as

```
shortLinesOnly :: String -> String  
shortLinesOnly input =   
    let allLines = lines input  
        shortLines = filter (\line -> length line < 10) allLines  
    in  unlines shortLines
```

You can also think of `let A in B` as pretty much equivalent to `B where A`.

Answer (score 1):

If Haskell was a procedural language, you would write the function body like so:

```
allLines = lines input
shortLines = filter (\line -> length line < 10) allLines
return unlines shortLines
```

Converting this directly to the functional style would result in

```
let allLines = lines input
    shortLines = filter (\line -> length line < 10) allLines
in unlines shortLines
```

So, why bother with results? For better readability. The `let` statement usually stand for "define some parameters to be used in the main expression". But here `unline shortLines` is not the "main expression" of the function - it's just the final stage of the computation. To prevent it from taking the focus, another stage was added - namely `result = unline shotLines`. Now the "main expression" is `result`, which isn't really that interesting so it doesn't take the focus from the previous parts of the computation.