# How do I define a value with "type" in Haskell's "let" expression?

Tags: parsing, haskell, let

I was trying to define a value with specific type like "Int", but seems Prelude doesn't support it?

```
Prelude> let c::Int = 4
Prelude| 

<interactive>:49:8:
    Illegal type signature: ‘Int’
      Perhaps you intended to use ScopedTypeVariables
    In a pattern type-signature
Prelude> let [Int]c=4
Prelude| 

<interactive>:51:5: Parse error in pattern: [Int]
```

How to correct it?

Comment: Type signatures can appear on the own line (in let, where, or top level declarations) or in expressions.  Type signatures are not for the left hand side of a binding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-line commands in GHCi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443035/multi-line-commands-in-ghci)

Comment: "How to correct it?" - the error says how - "Perhaps you intended to use ScopedTypeVariables". Enable ScopedTypeVariables in ghci with `:set -XScopedTypeVariables`. That is, if you want to use this particular syntax.

Comment: I came here thinking somebody wanted to put a `type` declaration inside a `let` block. I just went to check the Report to see if you can legally do that... You can't. (You *can*, however, put a fixity declaration in there... Weird, eh?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it

```
let x = 1::Int
```

Answer (score 8):

In a Haskell file, type declarations are provided separately from definitions, usually on the line before:

```
c :: Int    -- Type declaration
c = 4       -- Definition
```

This holds true for local definitions, as well as global ones; you just need to make sure the indentation lines up.  So in that case, we have

```
let c :: Int
    c = 4
in c + c
```

In Haskell, newlines and indentation can be replaced with braces and semicolons, and sometimes the braces can be elided.  In GHCi, where entering multiple-line input requires [some extra machinery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8443035/237428), you'll usually want the semicolon-separated variant; to wit, that'll be

```
let c :: Int ; c = 4
```

(The lack of an `in` is because GHCi behaves a bit like a `do` block; [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8274650/237428) has more information.)

However, it looks from your prompt like you have `:set +m` turned on, so you can use the multi-line option too:

```
Prelude> let c :: Int
Prelude|     c = 4
Prelude|
Prelude>
```

(Also, if you want to add a type annotation afterward, `let c = 4 ; c :: Int` works fine; it's just not the best style for a file you're working on.)

---

Also, an important note: you aren't using "Prelude", you're using [GHCi](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#idp46760125594256), GHC's interactive Haskell environment.  [`Prelude`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html) is the module that is imported by default in all Haskell programs (it provides the definitions of [`Bool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bool), [`Eq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq), [`(.)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.), and so on).  GHCi's default prompt contains the list of all modules currently imported, so by default it's `Prelude>`; however, if you type `import Data.Function`, the prompt will change to `Prelude Data.Function>`.