# Haskell boolean expressions : parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

Tags: haskell

I am trying out my hands on Haskell.

I wrote the code and saved it as : `boolean.hs`

The code is:

```
let area r = pi * r ^ 2
main = print(area 5 < 50)
```

When I do, `ghc -o boolean boolean.hs`

I get an error message :

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( boolean.hs, boolean.o )

boolean.hs:2:1:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

It would be great if somebody helped me see how this error can be tackled.

I went through [Haskell|Wikibooks|Identation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation), and changed the code to :

```
let 
    area r = pi * r ^ 2
main = 
    print(area 5 < 50)
```

And still got :

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( boolean.hs, boolean.o )

boolean.hs:3:1:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

Regards. :)

Comment: related question about [let](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274650/in-haskell-when-do-we-use-in-with-let)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `let`. Just define the function and call it in `main` i.e.

```
area r = pi * r ^ 2

main = print (area 5 < 50)
```

Comment: Got it...thanks :) Can you tell me why this happens? Or can you point me into the direction into how can I learn more?

Comment: Sure, here's the link: https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html. Look at section 4.5

Comment: @PragyadityaDas Bare `let` expressions are not allowed to appear at the top level of a module but they can appear inside expressions (`let x = 42 in x * x`) or `do` blocks (`do { let x = 42; print x; }`).